# When to capitlize in a Title or message

Tags: capitalization

On my website, I will have an error message that says:

```
* Please Choose an Option
```

Should `an` be upper or lower case?

Comment: Capitalize the first word only unless others are proper nouns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'an' should be lower-case. Generally speaking, articles (**a**, **an**, and **the**) are not capitalized in titles.